# Div fill remaining height of parent with absolute

Tags: html, css, row-height

I need a div which height is the remaining of its parent.

[Like this fiddle](//jsfiddle.net/swsquy5r/1/)

CSS:

```
.h_100
{
    height:100%
}

body, html
{
    margin:0; 
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

.table
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.table_row
{
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
}
```

But it dosent seem to work in IE

Any suggestions how to solve my problem ?

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: The first fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/S8g4E/1360/

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure what you're looking for. but this shows how you can use an absolutely positioned wrapper with a table div inside of it to auto fill the wrapper.

http://jsfiddle.net/hyvgy36s/1/

```
#wrapper {
    position:absolute;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
#container {
    display:table;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working example.

```
#container {
    display:table;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}
```